# The .gitignore does not catch the .terraform directory

Tags: git, github, terraform-provider-aws

I encountered the following error when pushing the local repository to a remote repository.

```
error: File stage/services/webserver-cluster/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.39.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.39.0_x5 is 278.77 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Below are the files in the webserver-cluster directory:

```
.gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 1 armzig armzig 4096 Nov 28 17:58 .terraform
-rw-r--r-- 1 armzig armzig 1377 Nov 28 17:58 .terraform.lock.hcl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 armzig armzig 3510 Nov 28 15:40 main.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 armzig armzig  254 Nov 28 15:05 outputs.tf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 armzig armzig  124 Nov 28 15:05 variables.tf
```

```
 //.gitignore
    .terraform/
    *.tfstate
    *.tfstate.*
    terraform
    **/.terraform/*
    *.tfstate.backup
    terraform.tfstate
    terraform.tfstate.backup
```

How can I resolve this error?

Actions taken:

```
I removed the terraform directory from my working tree.
 I used git ls-files to verify that the terraform directory does not exist in the index directory.
 I run git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .terraform' on the top working directory.
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your `.gitignore` file

Comment: Thank you @ChrisDoyle. The //.gitignore is the contents of my .gitignore file. Please feel free to ask me any questions.

Comment: This "git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch stage/services/webserver-cluster/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.39.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.39.0_x5' HEAD " works for me!